# Create and fill temp table

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, temporary-tables

I have a stored procedure that selects some data and returns it. Now I also want to add a temp table, fill it with data and return it with the stored procedure.

I define it as follows:

```
create table #tempDateTable
(
    Name varchar,
    TempDate datetime
)

INSERT INTO #tempDateTable(Name, TempDate) values ('Smith', @myDate)
SELECT * FROM #tempDateTable
```

`@myDate` is parameter passed to the stored procedure.

When I execute the stored procedure it gives me:

```
Msg 8152, Level 16, State 14, Procedure date_samples_procedure, Line 90
String or binary data would be truncated.
```

What I find strange is that `Line 90` is not any of the above shown lines, but if I remove all the code for this `#tempDateTable`, the stored procedure works normally.

Comment: Varchar without size it`s varchar(1) that why it truncates the data.

Comment: Using a table-valued function is almost always more appropriate than this type of construct using a stored procedure + temporary table.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should specify the length of the varchar column e.g. varchar(2000).